# Consume own API from linked bot

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking to do the following, but have not been able to conceptualize the required steps to make this work:

- I have a user sign-up to my website using default Laravel Auth (table: users)
- I then want the user to connect/link their messenger account (e.g. Telegram or FB Messenger) to that website account. (table: services_users)
- Once linked and verified, I want the user to be able to send commands that consume the website APIs under that linked user account.

In the http request (get) I will need to send some kind of bearer token, but I am unsure how, when and where to create and set this. I've tested creating a Personal Access Token, which works, but I can't imagine it is good practice to store that PA token in the database.

Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/master/socialite). That will take care of authentication via facebook and many other providers.

Comment: Appreciate that thought Anders. I have that in place for login indeed, and it might help with the FB Messenger side of things. But not the Telegram one. I'd primarily like to understand how to make requests from any of my other channels (Telegram, WeChat, etc) to my endpoints using the user's credentials.

Comment: Got it. What about using session storage? Or maybe creating tokens at each request thus not need for database?